# Override a function already attached to an event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to override a function already attached to an event. Like that :

```js
let orFn = () => {
  console.log('old');
};

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', orFn);

orFn = () => {
  console.log('new');
};
```

However, when I click on the button, the old function is still called.
I have seen this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699739/override-function-expression-event-listener-not-working). I can't use a function wrapper in my case. And I want to understand why this is not working.

My code is available for testing here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gez8vac2/6/).

Comment: It's not working because you set a reference to a function. Just because you redefined the reference later doesn't mean the reference captured by `addEventListener` changed. The old function doesn't magically disappear. You can *remove* a handler and add a new one.

Comment: so the old reference binds to the addEventListener and there is now way to change it?

Comment: Redefining a reference doesn't change its value elsewhere--it's like writing `let foo = () => "bar"; let bar = foo; foo = () => "plugh";` `bar` gets a reference to `foo`'s value at the time `bar` is defined. Changing `foo` has zero effect on `bar`'s reference. You can remove the handler and add a new one. You can keep the old one and add a new one. You can wrap `addEventListener` and do whatever you want. But JS semantics are JS semantics.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks. It's so clear now.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to remove first listener, then add another one

```js
let orFn = () => {
  console.log('old');
};

let orFnNew = () => {
  console.log('new');
};

var buttonEl = document.querySelector('button')

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', orFn);

// remove old listener
buttonEl.removeEventListener('click', orFn);

// add another one
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', orFnNew);
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Another way is to have one listener, that may call different functions inside. Example:

```js
// button
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('button')

const orFn = () => {
  console.log('old');
};

const orFnNew = () => {
  console.log('new');
};

// function that will be called
let functionToCall = orFn;

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => { // single listener
  
  functionToCall.call(event); // call a function with event


  functionToCall = functionToCall === orFn ? orFnNew : orFn; // change function to be called
});
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of using bind().

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let orFn = () => {
  alert('old');
};

orFn = () => {
  alert('new');
};

orFn.bind(orFn)

btn.addEventListener('click', orFn);
```

This will bind with new function and show `new` in alert Popup.

Comment: Hey @MarcF. I have changed the code and put function above the event call